# Makefile % match-anything rule picks up "Makefile" target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a universal Makefile to sync the source tree with some remote host, ssh into it and execute make there, forwarding any targets or variable overrides

So far I came up with this:

```
HOST ?= host
DIR ?= ~/dev

SRC = src

all:

.PHONY: sync
sync:
    rsync -azP --exclude ".*/" --exclude ".*" $(SRC)/ $(HOST):$(DIR)

%: sync
    ssh $(HOST) 'cd $(DIR) && make $@ MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)'
```

It works great as long as I omit `sync` in the dependency list of `%` target. Once I add it back in, `Makefile` target is picked up for some reason, causing it to ssh into the remote machine and run `make Makefile`, which is not a valid target or expected behaviour

To clarify, I don't specify `Makefile` as a target myself. I do

```
make
make clean
```

All of which result in `Makefile` target being run regardless

Comment: Maybe add `Makefile` as an explicit target, with empty recipe and no dependencies?

Comment: Make normally attempts to build Makefile as a target, as well as any files included into the makefile.  This can be used to update the Makefile when the source changes, e.g. keep auto-dependencies correct.  It would usually do nothing, which is what it seems like it would do this when it runs the make command remotely.

Comment: Without the `sync` phony dependency, make will see that `Makefile` exists and has no dependencies, and thus doesn't need to be remade, and so it doesn't run the recipe.  But once it has a phony dependency, it appears to always need to be remade, since its dependency (`sync`) is always remade, and the recipe is run.  You could avoid that like @HolyBlackCat said, as that will keep the pattern rule from being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNU `make` automatically attempts to rebuild the makefile(s) before building the designated targets or default target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles).  Other `make` implementations do not necessarily do this.  The GNU `make` manual contains this advice about your particular problem:

> If you know that one or more of your makefiles cannot be remade and
> you want to keep make from performing an implicit rule search on them,
> perhaps for efficiency reasons, you can use any normal method of
> preventing implicit rule look-up to do so. For example, you can write
> an explicit rule with the makefile as the target, and an empty recipe
> [...]

The empty recipe approach would be to add a rule such as this:

```
Makefile: ;
```

With that present in your makefile (and the file's name being `Makefile`), when `make` looks for a rule with which to rebuild `Makefile` it will choose that explicit, empty rule instead of the match-anything wildcard rule.  It would be a little more robust to write that like this, however:

```
$(MAKEFILE_LIST): ;
```

The `MAKEFILE_LIST` variable contains the names of all the makefiles that `make` read, so it will cover you even if you add `include` directives to your makefile or if you access it from a different directory or via a different name by use of the `-f` command-line option.

Comment: Thanks, this also helped me solve an issue where the match-anything rule was picking up one of the prerequisites of another rule as a target, thus calling it a circular dependency and dropping it.